# Anylogic - Error during model creation: how to identify?

Tags: model, anylogic, creation

Anylogic version 8.3.3 PLE.

Running the model I get:

> "Error while drawing animation frame.
>   Possibly caused by dynamic properties of animation shapes.
>   The picture will be restored when (and if) the error goes away."

Console view does not include any names of any elements of the model to identify where the problem is.

The model worked the day before.

Comment: this can be anything

Comment: Well, yes. That is the problem. BTW, it is an SD model. So far as I can tell, with my minimal experience of it, the software (console view) does not provide any information of any use to narrow down the problem. I haven't added any charts since the prior successful run. No variables, stocks or flows either.

Comment: Well, if you didn't use versioning (always do!), you will have to either use a much older version or build your model backwards step by step. You must have changed something between the day before and now. This error does not appear out of nowhere. Agree though that some better guidance would be helpful. Start with removing all UI elements such as rectangles, ... Anything you can ignore that does not impact the model functionality. Also charts! Good luck

Comment: Benjamin, thanks. I already concluded it was a waste of time trying to find the problem and reverted to the previous saved version. The difference between the two is just a couple of hours work. Also started removing clutter, redundant elements, etc. Moving on.

Comment: @MMacG it's important to test what your model is doing more often (not every 2 hours)... Also validating constantly, otherwise your model becomes a huge mess full of bugs.

Comment: I do. I normally save only after I test and debug each change. This time, i can only conclude I saved it after making a change but before testing, though I don't recall doing so. Since I apparently saved it with whatever error, and the software reporting is worthless in regards to actually identifying the where this type of error is, I reverted to my prior archived version, which was only about two hours older.  I hope that clarifies it. no problems since.

Answer (score 1):

Same error occurred again. This time there was no question of any changes to the model itself. 
I had only been examining various scenarios using different data for the Table functions.

I use Excel to prepare the data tables for import to the database, sometimes doing calculations in the worksheet before finalising the data. Then I  copy paste value the data in columns A and B, and delete the columns containing formulas and inputs.

I reviewed the Excel data tables. I found a value in cell F1.

I deleted column F. Then I ran the model to include the data and it functioned without error.